# How to add multiple items to a panel in ext.js?

Tags: extjs, label, panel, textfield, items

I am trying to add two text fields below a label in a panel, code for the same is below:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'form',
    layout: 'anchor',
    bodyStyle: {
        background: 'none',
        padding: '10px',
        border: '0',
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'label',
        html: 'Enter System Name',
        padding: '150px',
        cls: 'label'
    }, {
        xtype: 'label',
        html: '<i class="fa fa-television fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
        padding: '270px',
        cls: 'image'
    }, {
        name: 'systemName',
        xtype: 'textfield',
        margin: '0 0 0 155px',
        padding: '60px',
        anchor: '65%',
    }],
}],
```

Now, I do get the all the items on the form, but the text fields also appear as a label, as in I am not able to enter any value in it.
It would be great if somebody could help me out the mistake I am doing here.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: give some fiddle if possible

Comment: I don't get it. You say you want 1 label and 2 textfields below it, but your code has 2 labels and only 1 textfield. label 1 says 'Enter System Name', label 2 shows an image of television and the textfield you added works properly. I would also suggest to remove all the trailing commas first. Can you explain a bit more what you exactly want?

Comment: It seems like I have figured out the issue here, I have put the padding for the labels as 150px and 270px respectively, due to which the textfield area was being overlapped by the label area.
Now, setting the padding only to left & right, like :

padding: '0 150px 0 150px'

resolves the issue.
Anyway, thanks for your time and I do still have a lot to learn :)